# SML syntax error found at EQUALOP

Tags: pattern-matching, syntax-error, sml

I have to write a program about checking if an element e belongs to the list L and then return true.
I prefer not to use if, so i try with pattern matching.

I write this code:

```
member (e, []) = false
   |member (e, h=e::rest) = true
   |member (e, h::rest) = member (e, rest);
```

And i get ''Syntax error found at EQUALOP''. 
Can anybody explain what i had to change?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `=` (or any other operators or functions) in a pattern.

You'll need to use the `(e, h::rest)` pattern, where you then use an `if e = h then ... else ...` to check if they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

This would be closer to a valid syntax:

```
fun member (e, []) = false
   |member (e, h as (e::rest)) = true
   |member (e, h::rest) = member (e, rest);
```

Note the “h as …”.

Still wrong as the “e” is duplicated in the second pattern, and that's not allowed.

This is syntactically correct:

```
fun member (e, []) = false
   |member (e, h as (e2::rest)) = true
   |member (e, h::rest) = member (e, rest);
```

But still not logically correct. As Sebastien mentioned, with the intent you had, the second pattern `member (e, h as (e2::rest))` is better written as `member (e, h::rest)`, which is the same as the third pattern and so is better dropped to retain only two patterns out of the three.

> I have to write a program about checking if an 
>   element e belongs to the list L

Apart the original syntax error, you can't check for `e` is in the list, with pattern, as in patterns, variables are not interpreted like constants. In patterns, only constants stands for their value, and on the contrary, variables, will be assigned a value by *destructuring*. Ex. you could check for the presence of something like `true` or `false`, which would stand for their own, but not for a variable (this is how SML is defined). You need to use `if … then … else` even if you would like to use pattern only.

Just out of curiosity, you may be interested in the hypothetical sML (Successor ML) which wanted to have guarded pattern matching: [Match guards (successor-ml.org)](http://successor-ml.org/index.php?title=Match_guards).